# Deploy on azure continous delivery custom node app

Tags: node.js, azure, continuous-delivery

I have a node app that has both a react native front end and a node API

I want to be able to just run npm install for both folders and then just have it run the start command "node server" (node/server/index.js) to have the node app running.

But I can't seem to figure out the release tasks to make this happen.

I am using the preview continous delivery that connects to visual studio online

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it has nothing to do with continuous delivery. Since Azure App Service runs on Microsoft IIS, you'll need to have an IIS configuration file named `web.config` and should include the following section to match your requirement:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="./node/server/index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
</handlers>
```

This indicates that the `node/server/index.js` file is a node.js site to be handled by the [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) module.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
    </rule>

    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./node/server/index.js"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

These rewrite rules determine where your static content and dynamic content should be located in.

For a completed `web.config` file you can check [this post](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps) out.